# Exclude part of string using Regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have an address like

```
New street 4 
462005 MG Road 
Tel .: 02281 / 93-1-212  
Fax .: 02681 / 93-1148
```

I want string before "Tel" and remove whatever comes after "Tel"

```
New street 4 
462005 MG Road
```

What i have tried is

```
(?!^Tel$)(^.*$)
```

But its only gives first line. *New street 4*

How can be achieve this using regular expression without any PHP function.

Comment: Oh, `without any PHP function`.. missed that important update.

Comment: @Adas Please notice that I updated my answer so you won't get screwed when a street name includes the string `Tel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to activate single line mode:

```
(?s).*?(?=Tel)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dX7kU7/1

*edit*:
 
A little improvement: this updated version should be a tad more robust and stop when a new line starts with `Tel`, i.e. you won't get screwed when a street name includes the substring `Tel`: https://regex101.com/r/dX7kU7/2

Comment: Bingo...exactly what i need. thank you very much @timgeb

Comment: @Adas no problem, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

Replace

```
([\s\S]*?)(Tel[\s\S]*)
```

With

```
$1
```

Comment: It gives with Tel, and i don't want that, i want only first two lines of address.

Answer (score 0):

Be original! )))

```
if (false !== $pos = strpos($str, 'Tel')) {
    $str = substr($str, 0, $pos);
}
```